# What is the oxidation state of nitrogen in N2O5?

Tags: oxidation-state

According to the formula it should be +5 but according to its structure shouldn't it be +4? How is it +5 then?

[image]

Comment: $5\cdot(-2) + 2\cdot(+5)  = 0$

Comment: But according to the structure it should be + 4

Comment: No. Why do you think so?

Comment: A coordinate bond gives a formal charge of +1 to N, implying that it effectively gets a raise in oxidation state by +2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is +5 .Even by the structure.

[image]

Notice that it is a resonance structure of:

[image]

Now one of the bonds are coordinate bonds where nitrogen donates BOTH its electrons to oxygen (otherwise, oxygen cannot have a single bond without a negative charge and no peroxy type linkage).

So, while determining oxidation state from the structure :

O.N=+2+2+1=+5

**References:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_pentoxide

Comment: Your second image is better since it shows formal charges.

Comment: True, but that's not much of an improvement. Evidently, I picked it up for representation purpose.

Comment: Oh, I always advocate properly assigning formal charges to all atoms that need them, which is why I wouldn’t have upvoted your answer if only the first structure were shown ;)